# How can I get Vue Router to append the 'link-exact-active-class' at the end of the classlist?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to highlight the active link inside my navigation bar by using the `linkExactActiveClass` parameter in the router construtor.
My issue is that the active class is being added at the start of the css class list, which means that other classes overwrite it.

##### Here is my router configuration:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
  linkExactActiveClass: 'text-yellow-500',
});
```

##### The `router-link` element looks like this:

```
<li>
    <router-link class="px-2 text-white" to="/manage">Manage</router-link>
</li>
```

##### The issue:

The `text-yellow-500` class does get added before the already existing css classes. This results in the yellow text being overwritten by the `text-white` class. How can I change this?

[image: class gets added at the start]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround is to prepend a `!` in your class using the **built-in important modifier** of tailwind [(docs)](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier)

Try to use it in this way:

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
  linkExactActiveClass: '!text-yellow-500',
});
```

Usually, I don't like this approach, but I think there are no other simple options

PS: make sure you're using at least tailwind 2.1 with the [JIT](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode) mode

Comment: This worked for me - but I also had to add the router config file (.js ending) to the purge attribute inside the tailwind config file since this was the only time I've been using `text-yellow-500`.